# How to show session errors in the index page for wrong id password?

Tags: javascript, php

I think this question has been answered many times. But still i didn't find a suitable solution. i want to display "wrong id/password" message in my admin_login.php page itself when my id and password do not match. how to do it? Please help. Here is my code

admin_login.php

```
<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['error_message']))
{ 
?>
    alert("<?php echo $_SESSION['error_message']; ?>");
 <?php 
   unset($_SESSION['error_message']); 
 } 
 ?>
</script>
<section class="container">
<div class="login">
  <h1>Login to Admin Panel</h1>
  <form method="post" action="admin_logincode.php" enctype="multipart/form-  data">
    <p><input type="text" name="uname" id= "uname" value="" placeholder="Username or Email"></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
    <p class="remember_me">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
        Remember me on this computer
      </label>
    </p>
    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
  </form>
</div>
</section>
</body>
```

This is my php code: admin_logincode.php

```
<?php 
include ("connection.php");
session_start();
$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
if($uname=="admin" && $password=="2015admingoswami")
{
    $_SESSION['uname']=$uname;
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + 120;
    header("location:admin_home.php");
}
else
{ 
    $_SESSION['error_message']="Wrong Username or Password";
    header("location:admin_login.php");
}
?>
```

I have done the coding part to display the error message but still it didn't work. Please help me out.

Comment: you are vulnerable to javascript injection errors. never ever dump text from php directly into a JS context. you can kill all of the scripts on the page. always output via `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also can make an AJAX call (with jQuery) when the submit button of your admin_login.php page is clicked, and the target of the call would be admin_logincode.php. The result of the AJAX call could be appended to any part of your form (a DIV for instance) so you can append here "wrong password" without refreshing the login page. If the login/pass match, then admin_logincode.php will initiate a session.

Just check on your index page if the session exists, almost like as you did.

```
//if session exists, then user is authentified
if (isset($_SESSION['auth'])) {
    //display the user menu, or whatever
}

//else display the login form
else {
    display_login();
}
```

Don't forget to "never trust the client" so you have to be careful when handling data posted by the user. Check special chars, length...and pay attention to fields you use to perform MySQL requests.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're not forgetting to call `session_start()` on the page where you want to print the error.